# Get rows where created date is older than 14 days

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

This is the case:

In my database I have a table **deployments**. The rows in the table also have a field **created_at**. Now I would like to select all rows where the created_date is **older than 14 days**. But I'm stuck on how to do this with **Carbon**. My query now looks like this:

```
$passed = Deployment::where('created_at', '>=', );
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `'now() - interval 14 day'`?

Comment: Something like this:    Carbon::now()->subWeeks(2)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `subDays()` method:

```
$passed = Deployment::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14)->toDateTimeString());
```

Comment: It seems to work even without `->toDateTimeString()` in the end. `Carbon::now()->subDays(14)`. Is `toDateTimeString()` needed?

Comment: I know this thread is quite old, but checking for `>=` will return the elements that are "younger" than 12 days, you say you want to check for elements that are "older", so I think you should be checking for `<=`.

Comment: toDateTimeString() is actually *wrong*. I suppose the original author is used MySQL as a DB, however when you use MongoDB for example you should pass Carbon object, so it would be treat properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Carbon::now()->subDays(14)

```
    $passed = Deployment::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14)->toDateTimeString());
```

You can read more about Carbon its feature here [Carbon Documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)